# Disable HTML autofix in Chrome

Tags: html, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am creating NODE.js app that use Nunjucks as view engine. I added tests to verify if the html created is valid (for now I just wanted to check if all tags are properly closed). In order to do this i spin up application, go to the site using headless chrome, making a snapshot and running validation code on output files.

The problem is that browsers try to fix HTML code automatically. They close tags by themself in order to create more or less valid HTML. Is there a way to disable this feature?

I would like to be sure that i created valid HTML document using nunjucks rather then counting that browser will fix it itself.

Comment: If you validate the source directly, Chrome will not change the HTML.
Try this in your browser: `view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091531/disable-html-autofix-in-chrome`

If you use the developer panel to inspect the DOM, Chrome tries to correct poor html. :) 

You could maybe just do a GET request to the application, and validate the result, instead of using Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, i went with just making GET request with axios :).

Comment: Cool! I created an answer you can accept. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you validate the source directly, Chrome will not change the HTML. Try this in your browser: `view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091531/disable-html-autofix-in-chrome`
If you use the developer panel to inspect the DOM, Chrome tries to correct poor html.

You could maybe just do a GET request to the application, and validate the result, instead of using Chrome.